# c++ pass-by-value, pass-by-reference or pass by value result

Tags: c++

Is this Correct:

Pass by value = 
1
1

pass-by-reference
0
0

pass by value result
1
1

```
int i;
int a[2];

void inc (int x,int y ) {
  x++;
  y++;
}

int main() {
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 1;
  i = 0;
  inc (a[i],a[i]);
  cout << a[0] << endl << a[1] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more clue how sentences above the code related to it?

Comment: Where is the function where you pass by reference?

Comment: If it actually was pass-by-reference, `a[0]` would be 2, and `a[1]` would obviously still be 1 because it's never changed.

Comment: @chris Will a[0] be equal to 3 won' t it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Yes, I don't know why I started from 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function inc does not change the original values of array a. It accepts arguments by values that is it deals with copies of the arguments.

If you want that the function would change the arguments it should be defined like

```
void inc (int &x,int &y ){
    x++;
    y++;
}
```

In this case for a function call like this

```
i = 0;
inc (a[i],a[i]);
```

the output will be

```
3 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void inc (int x,int y ){
x++;
y++;
```

}
your function inc will not increase the values when you call it in you main() function. because x and y are local values to inc, after inc finished, the memory of x and y will be deleted by the complier. SO, x and y not dose not exist any more. if you want the values that are passed into inc be increase( in which case pass by reference) you could define you inc like this

```
void inc(int &x, int&y) {
     x++;
     y++;
```

}

by doing this, you are pass the memory address of x and y into in(in you case addresses of a[0] and a [1]), then you function deference the addresses to get the values, and increase the values by 1, then store the values back to the addresses.